# Add LibMMS to an iPhone Project

Tags: iphone, libmms

Can anyone help?

I compiled the LibMMS project that comes with the WunderRadio application fine as part of my other project. It has the liblibmms.a file and I added it as a dependency to the main project.

The problem is that I cannot see any off the LibMMS headers so I cannot import mms.h or mmsx.h into any .m file.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

in

- xCode create a new group folder and name it 'external projects'.
- Right click on this folder and choose 'Add files to [your app]'
- Browse to Wunderradio App and choose folders MMS and FFMPEG
- click 'Add'

You have now imported the projects into your xcode project. Additional to adding the libmms to the main project you should also add the libmms.a to your framework-group.